# How to show a buffer (progress bar) in video QML

Tags: qt, video, qml, progress-bar, buffer

I would like to show a buffer in a video, similar to youtube videos. I read the documentation on [Video Qml Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-qtmultimedia-video.html)

and there is `bufferProgress` property that "holds how much of the data buffer is currently filled, from 0.0 (empty) to 1.0 (full)", but this property can't be assigned with a value, so I don't know how should I use it.
I googled, but I couldn't find a similar problem that has been solved.
Here is my code:

```
    Video{
                 id:video
                 //width:500
                 //height:300
                 anchors.top:rect3.bottom
                 autoLoad: true
                 autoPlay: true
                 width:isFullScreen? window.width : 500
                 height:isFullScreen?window.height : 300
                 Layout.fillHeight: isFullScreen
                 Layout.fillWidth: isFullScreen


                 Image{
                     id:play_from_start_image
                     width:parent.width/5
                     height:parent.height/5
                     anchors.right:play_image.left
                     anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                     source:'qrc:play-from-start.png'
                     opacity:timer3.running?1.0:0.0
                     Behavior on opacity {
                         PropertyAnimation { duration: 5000 }
                     }

                     Timer{
                         id:timer3
                         interval:5000
                         running: true
                  }

                     MouseArea{
                         anchors.fill:parent
                         onClicked:{
                             timer3.start()
                             video.seek(0)
                             video.play()
                         }
                     }




                 }

                 Image{
                     id:stop_image
                     width:parent.width/5-20
                     height:parent.height/5-20
                     anchors.left:play_image.right
                     anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                     source:'qrc:stop-button.png'
                     opacity:timer4.running?1.0:0.0
                     Behavior on opacity {
                         PropertyAnimation { duration: 5000 }
                     }

                     Timer{
                         id:timer4
                         interval:5000
                         running:true
                  }


                       MouseArea{
                        anchors.fill:parent
                        onClicked:{
                            timer4.start()
                            video.pause()
                        }

                       }



                 }

                 Image{
                     id:play_image
                     width:parent.width/5
                     height:parent.height/5
                     anchors.centerIn: parent
                     source:'qrc:play.svg'
                     opacity:timer1.running?1.0:0.0
                     Behavior on opacity {
                         PropertyAnimation { duration: 5000 }
                     }

                     Timer{
                         id:timer1
                         interval:5000
                         running:true
                  }


                       MouseArea{
                        anchors.fill:parent
                        onClicked:{
                            if(video.playbackState===1){
                                  timer1.start()
                                  video.pause()
                                  play_image.source='qrc:play.svg'

                                }else if(video.playbackState===2){
                                  video.play()
                                  play_image.source='qrc:pause.svg'
                                  timer1.stop()


                               }
                          }
                       }

                   }

                 Image{
                     id:enter_exit_image
                     width:parent.width/5
                     height:parent.height/5
                     anchors.top:video.top
                     anchors.right:video.right
                     source: isFullScreen? 'qrc:enter-outline.svg':'qrc:exit-outline.svg'
                     opacity:timer2.running?1.0:0.0
                     Behavior on opacity {
                         PropertyAnimation { duration: 5000 }
                     }

                     Timer{
                         id:timer2
                         interval:5000
                         running:true
                     }


                     MouseArea{
                        anchors.fill:parent

                          onClicked:{
                              timer2.start()
                              isFullScreen=!isFullScreen
                              //timer2.stop()

                          }


                      }

                 }

        }
```

This is a part of my code where the `video` component is, the rest is on Github and I can provide a link to my Github repository if needed.
Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Edit:
I found `progress bar` control in QML, I was googling it wrong for days. I included it in my code:

```
              Video{
                 id:video
                 //width:500
                 //height:300
                 anchors.top:rect3.bottom
                 autoLoad: true
                 autoPlay: true
                 width:isFullScreen? window.width : 500
                 height:isFullScreen?window.height : 300
                 Layout.fillHeight: isFullScreen
                 Layout.fillWidth: isFullScreen

                 ProgressBar{
                     id:buffer
                     from:start
                     to:end
                     value:new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
                     //indeterminate: true
                     anchors.bottom:video.bottom

                 }

        }
      ....
```

`start` is a start time defined in my xml file and `end` is the end time. `value` should be current time. This code only shows progress bar to half of the width of the video and it doesn't have any progress. What am I doing here wrong?

Comment: A ProgressBar's `value` property is a `real`, but you're assigning it a date/time string. That won't work. It needs something that can at least be interpreted as a numeric value.

Comment: Okay, I have tried  ```value:new Date().setTime()```   ,  ```value:new Date().getTime()```, ```value:Qt.formatTime(new Date(), "mm:ss")```  and couple of other possibilities, but nothing happens.

Comment: The `from` and `to` properties also need to be numeric.

Comment: They are in format ```hh:mm``` , for example  ```<start>9:00</start>```
       ```<end>17:00</end>```. I am not sure if they are correctly interpreted in ```XmlLisModel``` as ```XmlRole { name: "start"; query: "start/number()" }``` and
                               ```XmlRole { name: "end"; query: "start/number()" }```?

Comment: `9:00` is not a numeric format, that's a time format. You should stick to using the number of seconds or ms or something. Don't try to get fancy with time values when it's expecting a number.

Comment: You're right, it's just I'm not supposed to change xml file in which the data is.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is what you trying to achieve:

```
Video {
    id: video
    
    // Gray buffer bar
    ProgressBar {
        id: bufferBar
        anchors.bottom: video.bottom
        anchors.left: video.left
        width: video.width
        from: 0
        to: 1
        value: video.bufferProgress 
        contentItem: Rectangle {
            anchors.left: bufferBar.left
            anchors.bottom: bufferBar.bottom
            height: bufferBar.height
            width: bufferBar.width * bufferBar.visualPosition
            color: "lightgray"
            opacity: 0.75
        }
    }

    // Red position bar 
    ProgressBar {
        id: positionBar
        anchors.bottom: video.bottom
        anchors.left: video.left
        width: video.width
        from: 0
        to: video.duration
        value: video.position
        background: Item {
            visible: false
        }
        contentItem: Rectangle {
            anchors.left: positionBar.left
            anchors.bottom: positionBar.bottom
            height: positionBar.height
            width: positionBar.width * positionBar.visualPosition
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

I just wrote it top of my head, so there might be some mistakes.